# Profilinf C++ code wrapped by a pybind provided python interface

Tags: python, c++

I have C++ code that I wrapped with a python interface via Pybind, I was wondering if it is possible to profile my calculations which are ran in C++ but via the python interface (I run python3 my_script.py and inside the script C++ objects are made and C++ methods are called that are wrapped with pybind to python objects ) with something like linux-perf? Any help is well appreciated.